# Change from cartesian coordinates to cylindrical and spherical

Tags: spherical-coordinates, cylindrical-coordinates

I have 6 equations in Cartesian coordinates a) change to cylindrical coordinates b) change to spherical coordinate
This book show me the answers but i don't find it
If anyone can help me i will appreciate so much!
Thanks for your time

1) z = 2                                               a) z = 2                           b)ρcos(Φ) = 2

2) z = 5x² + 5y²                                    a) z = 5r²                         b)5ρ = cos(Φ)cosec²(Φ)

3) x² + y² + z² = 9                                a) r² + z² = 9                    b)ρ = 3

4) x² + y² + 2z² = 4                              a) r² +2z² = 4                    b)ρ² (1 + cos²(Φ) = 4

5) x² - y² -2z² = 1                                a) 2z² = r²cos(2θ)              b)ρ² (sin²(Φ)cos(2θ) -2cos²(Φ) = 1

6) x² + y² = 2x                                     a) r = 2cos(θ)                    b)ρsin(Φ) = 2cos(θ)

Comment: I can do the first because from Cartesian coordinates to a) z = z in cylindrical coordinates and b) z = ρcos(Φ) in spherical coordinates. But in the other exercises i can't find a way to solve it

Answer (score 1):

The conversion from Cartesian to cylindrical coordinates reads
$$ x=r\cos(\theta),\quad y=r\sin(\theta),\quad z=z\,, $$
and from Cartesian to spherical coordinates
$$ x=\rho\sin(\phi)\cos(\theta),\quad y=\rho\sin(\phi)\sin(\theta),\quad z=\rho\cos(\phi)\,. $$
Inserting this into the equations 1) - 6) should give you the posted solutions a) and b) for each case.